# Attribute value not saving

Tags: admin, magento-1.9.1.1, filterable-attributes

I am a web admin for a retailer and don't have access to the code for our Magento site, so I am hoping the fix to this issue is something done through the admin login. And please bear with my lack of technical knowledge!

A custom attribute used on the front end (brand name) does not save when editing individual products. We have found around 75% of our products, bulk imported from a CSV file, have not 'kept' the brand name from that import file.

When trying to edit these products individually, the 'brand name' dropdown value does not always get saved (sometimes it does, mostly it doesn't). The only way of reliably getting this attribute to save is to use the bulk 'Update Attributes' option, which is impractical.

Is anyone able to explain this, and/or offer a fix suggestion? It's a vitally important attribute from a user point of view, so people can filter by brand.

Cheers,

Hayden

Comment: so in the magento backend, on the product, the brand name options appear in the dropdown, and when you select one and save it doesn't show that selection when you reload the product?

Comment: most of the issues I've seen surrounding this problem are when an import file has a value that you don't have listed in the options for that attribute.  Making it a freeform textfield isn't a great solution if you want it to be a dropdown on the frontend.  I'd go the "map my ids" route.

Comment: 'Rightclick' - that is correct, the brand names are all listed in a dropdown, and it doesn't save when I select it. In further news, I batch edited a bunch of products and it appeared to work yesterday, but has since lost all of the data.

Comment: After you select it from the dropdown, you click `save` or `save & continue edit`, right?  Sorry if that was obvious but problems are often something like that.  And then clear caches?  Your issue with batch edit working and then reverting to something else is weird, I can't explain that!  Do you have any extensions or api setup to load data that would do that?  There is only one important thing that should be changing in a magento site on you....and that's a lot of new orders coming in.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having similar problems, if you have a long list of attribute values that doesn't get saved (completely), it could be the setting `max_input_vars`, by default it usually is 1000. Check `phpinfo()` to see what the current value is.

Comment: Tried to make to 3000 and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file will need to match the actual IDs of the brands if you are using a dropdown type attribute.

Check the field type under catalogue - attributes - manage attributes. 
The quickest way would be a vlookup in excel to match your brand names to the ids in magento.

Otherwise it could be related to your store view not being set correctly, e.g. if your brand field has the 'website' scope you may need to specify the website when you import it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the responses. The issue was actually found to be something to do with a cron update and an unexpected field forcing things to go blank when it couldn't find a match between our system and Magento. The more you know!

Comment: I am also having the same issue, please tell the issue in brief.